# How to select elements by css property

Tags: html, css

I have a third party library that add texts to my angular app, and I want to style it, unfortunately there is no class or specific element name to do css selector by.

My question is if is it possible to do css selector based on css property.

For example select all elements that are bold

I tried this but doesn't work and I get `SassError: Expected identifier`

```
ngx-contentful-rich-text {
  line-height: 2rem;

  *[font-weight=700] {
    margin-top: 2rem;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't, think that's possible in CSS. If the element has a custom or unique CSS attribute, you can use that. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors
The only other option really is to target the element by traversing the DOM.

Comment: you can use css attribute selector https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp

Answer (score -1):

You might want to use this:

```js
var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
function change() {
    var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
    for (i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
       if (getComputedStyle(paragraphs[i]).fontWeight == 700) {
            paragraphs[i].style.backgroundColor = '#00ff00';
       }
    }
}
```

Snippet:

```js
function change() {
    var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
    for (i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
       if (getComputedStyle(paragraphs[i]).fontWeight == 700) {
            paragraphs[i].style.backgroundColor = '#00ff00';
       }
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="change()">Change!</button>
<p style="font-weight:400;">Will not change.</p>
<p style="font-weight:700;">Will change.</p>
```

Comment: This is invalid CSS. See this JS Bin
https://jsbin.com/hiyoperede/edit?html,output

Comment: this is invalid css